# How should an accumulator in a Python clock be handled correctly?

Tags: python, methods, clock, accumulate

I'm writing a small clock object in Python that can be started, stopped and reset. I'm having difficulty knowing how to keep track of the accumulation of time correctly. Right now, the way the update procedure is written, the clock accumulates too much time (because of calls to the update method). I'm not sure how to write this such that it accumulates the correct time.

```
import time
import datetime

class Clock(object):

    def __init__(
        self,
        name  = None,
        start = True
        ):
        self._name  = name
        self._start = start # Boolean start clock on instantiation
        # If a global clock list is detected, add a clock instance to it.
        if "clocks" in globals():
            clocks.add(self)
        self.reset()
        if self._start:
            self.start()

    def start(self):
        self._startTime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def stop(self):
        self._startTime = None

    # Update the clock accumulator.
    def update(self):
        self.accumulator += (
            datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self._startTime
        )

    def reset(self):
        self.accumulator = datetime.timedelta(0)
        self._startTime  = None

    # If the clock has a start time, add the difference between now and the
    # start time to the accumulator and return the accumulation. If the clock
    # does not have a start time, return the accumulation.
    def elapsed(self):
        if self._startTime:
            self.update()
        return(self.accumulator)

    def time(self):
        return(self.elapsed().total_seconds())

clock = Clock()
print clock.time()
print "starting"; clock.start()
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(3)
    print clock.time()
print "stopping"; clock.stop()
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(3)
    print clock.time()
print "starting"; clock.start()
for i in range(4):
    time.sleep(3)
    print clock.time()
print "resetting"; clock.reset()
print clock.time()
```

Comment: What is your expected output times?  With a small change I have it outputting `0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 0`.  Is that desired?

Comment: Why are you adding the time since start, rather than just setting it to the time since start?

Comment: @Amber, you are right, except the way that `start` is written, if `update` was just setting `self.accumulator` rather than adding to it, then the `start` would essentially cause a reset.  Obviously this could be written so that was not the case, but as it stands it would break with that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add a call to `self.start()` at the end of `update` then I think it will work the way you are intending.

The reason you are seeing the issue with the current code is you are adding the total offset from `_startTime` to `now()` each time you update, but you only want the difference between `now()` and when the timer started on the first call.  On subsequent calls you want the difference between `now()` and the previous call to `update`.

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks for your help on that. Following from your comments, I've added another time data attribute to record the time of the last update call. That way, I'm not destroying the start time information (which I want to be able to print out).